# Ok and Cancel Button Not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button, user-interface

Why my Ok and Cancel Button are not showing up on the UI screen?  I see the form, the label and the text box but I can't see the Cancel and OK buttons.
To give you a background I am creating this dialog box programmatically and all I need a a couple of text boxes , and their labels of course.  And an OK and Cancel button .

All these sizes that I have used here is by trial and error as I am not much experienced in the UI control area of Visual C# 2010.

```
public void function x ()
{
    var fileNameDialog = new Form();
        fileNameDialog.Text = "Save New Name";
        Label fileLabel = new Label();
        fileLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 40);
        fileLabel.Text= "Enter Person Name";

        fileNameDialog.Controls.Add(fileLabel);
        TextBox fileTextBox = new TextBox();
        fileTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(fileLabel.Location.X + 300, fileLabel.Location.Y);
        fileTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 40);
        fileNameDialog.Controls.Add(fileTextBox);
        fileTextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        fileTextBox.Text= textboxValue;
        Button okButton = new Button();
        okButton.Visible = true;
        okButton.Text = "OK";
        okButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(fileTextBox.Location.X, fileTextBox.Location.Y - 80);
        fileNameDialog.Controls.Add(okButton);
        okButton.Click += new EventHandler(okButton_Click);
        Button cancelButton = new Button();
        cancelButton.Visible = true;
        cancelButton.Text = "Cancel";
        fileNameDialog.Controls.Add(cancelButton);
        cancelButton.Click += new EventHandler(cancelButton_Click);
        cancelButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(fileTextBox.Location.X+50, fileTextBox.Location.Y - 80);

        fileNameDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: try changing the `fileTextBox.location.Y - 80` to `fileTextbox.location.Y + 80`

Comment: Why are you creating the controls dynamically anyways?

Comment: @chancea : Thanks that was the problem

Comment: @PoweredByOrange:  What suggestions do you have?

Comment: So what's Y set to?. Most likely it's gone negative. Can't see any reason for a dynamic create of components, but OK/Cancel aren't candidiates for that anyway. Set the anchor's to bottom right at design time. If you want to disappeare them, then put in panel and align it at the bottom of the form.

Comment: @user1298925 You can just create a form, drag and drop and arrange the controls, and let the VS designer do the hard work for you.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fileTextbox.Location.Y is zero, so subtracting 80 puts in above the form.

Try `fileTextBox.Bottom + 4` or something like that.

Using the designer to create this dialog form is probably the better route to take.  Along with the placement of the controls, you can use Anchors to make the controls relate to the size of the form.